# edit and update text area in php

Tags: mysql, php-5.6

my php function is not working when im add my text area in form. other all input or working. if im add  **remark(text area)** in form edit function cant show text in that remark. other input is visible but i cant save it again

please help me to fined my error

**Code before "html"**

```
<?php

function renderForm($id, $vehicle_type, $duration, $amount,$remarks, $error)

{

?>
```

**my HTML form**

```
<form action=""  method="post"> 
                <div class="row">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6" class="form-group">
                    <label>Vehicle Type <span style="color:red;font-size:8px;"><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></label>
                        <select name="vehicle_type" class="form-control">
                        <option <?php echo ($vehicle_type=='Bicycle')?'selected':'' ?>>Bicycle</option>
                        <option <?php echo ($vehicle_type=='Bike')?'selected':'' ?>>Bike </option>
                        <option <?php echo ($vehicle_type=='Cars')?'selected':'' ?>>Cars </option>
                        <option <?php echo ($vehicle_type=='Truck')?'selected':'' ?>>Truck</option>
                        <option <?php echo ($vehicle_type=='Others')?'selected':'' ?>>Others</option>

                    </select>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6" class="form-group">
                    <label>Duration </label> <span style="color:red; font-size:8px; "><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                      <input type="text" value="<?php echo $duration; ?>" name="duration" class="form-control" maxlength="20" placeholder="Eg:  4 Hrs">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6" class="form-group">
                        <label><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> Amount</label> <span style="color:red;font-size:8px;"><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" class="form-control"  placeholder="00">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6" class="form-group">

                           <label>Remarks</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="remarks" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($remarks); ?> rows="3" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
                            </div>


                         <div id="butn"  class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
                         <button class="myButton" type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg">SAVE</button>
                         </div>

                        </div>
            </form>
```

**Code after "html"**

```
<?php

}







// connect to the database

include('connection.php');





// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{

// confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data

if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))

{

// get form data, making sure it is valid

$id = $_POST['id'];

$vehicle_type = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['vehicle_type']));

$duration = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['duration']));

$amount = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['amount']));

$remarks = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['remarks']));





if ($vehicle_type=='' || $duration=='' || $amount=='' || $remarks=='')

{

// generate error message

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';



//error, display form

renderForm($id, $vehicle_type, $duration, $amount, $remarks, $error);

}

else

{

// save the data to the database

mysql_query("UPDATE price_normal SET vehicle_type='$vehicle_type', duration='$duration', amount='$amount', remarks='$remarks', WHERE id='$id'")

or die(mysql_error());



// once saved, redirect back to the view page

header("Location: pnormal.php");

}

}

else

{

// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error

echo 'Error!';

}

}

else


{



// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)

{

// query db

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM price_normal WHERE id=$id")

or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);



// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse

if($row)

{



// get data from db

$vehicle_type = $row['vehicle_type'];

$duration = $row['duration'];

$amount = $row['amount'];

$remarks = $row['remarks'];





// show form

renderForm($id, $vehicle_type, $duration, $amount, $remarks,'');

}

else

// if no match, display result

{

echo "No results!";

}

}

else

// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error

{

echo 'Error!';

}

}

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the actual HTML in your browser.  You're rendering the "remarks" content *as an attribute* of the `textarea` element:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="remarks" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($remarks); ?> rows="3" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
```

It should be the *content* of that element:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="remarks" rows="3" placeholder="Enter ..."><?php echo htmlspecialchars($remarks); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id='31'' at line 1

Comment: @KRISHNAKANTH: Then you have an error in your SQL syntax.  Look at whichever query is producing that error and look at the very last thing before the `WHERE`.